# How to render component from a twig filter?

Tags: octobercms

I would like to make a filter which replace some text by a rendered component. Since component need the controller to render themselves, and the plugin class have no access to it, I have no idea how to achieve that properly.

```php
// ...

// Within my plugin
public function registerMarkupTags()
{
    return [
        'filters' => [
            'myfilter' => function($content){
                $render = RenderMyComponentPlease('my-component') // <- Rendering the component
                return str_replace('[SLUG]', $render, $content);  // Replace within the text
            }
        ]
    ];
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I didn't notice that the controller is a Singleton, the controller could be retrieve with the static method getController().

Here is a possible solution :

```
// ...

// Within my plugin
public function registerMarkupTags()
{
    return [
        'filters' => [
            'myfilter' => function($content){
                $controller = Controller::getController(); // Retrieve the controller
                $controller->addComponent('MyPluginPath\Components\MyComponent', 'my-component', [], false); // Add my component to the page
                $render =  $controller->renderComponent('my-component', []); // <- Rendering the component
                return str_replace('[SLUG]', $render, $content);  // Replace within the text
            }
        ]
    ];
}

// ...
```